# Print output R shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, printing, output

can anyone explain to me how to view an output on r shiny?
The code of my app is very long, you can find it at this link [Print output on R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72459598/print-output-on-r-shiny) that is a very similar question, however, I have not received an answer.
My question is: once I have created a dataframe, how do I print it? I insert the most important part of the code in my opinion:

```
 shiny::observeEvent(input$modmatbut, {
    disegno<<-as.data.frame(oa.design(factor.names=values$levnames))
    })
```

input$modmatbut is when is when the button is pressed.
This function works (I insert the photo of an output obtained and as you can see it is a dataframe)
Now, I would like diesgno to be printed on the screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WObkr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Can you maybe switch to using `eventReactive`  and access the table via `disegno()`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("modmatbut","modmatbut"),
  tableOutput("draw")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  disegno <- eventReactive(input$modmatbut,{
    as.data.frame(oa.design(factor.names=values$levnames))
  })
  
  output$draw <- renderTable({
    disegno()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks for trying but nothing is displayed and indeed as if I write disegno in the console I get this: reactive({
    hybrid_chain(eventFunc(), function(value) {
        if (ignoreInit && !initialized) {
            initialized <<- TRUE
            req(FALSE)
        }
        req(!ignoreNULL || !isNullEvent(value))
        isolate(valueFunc())
    })
})

Comment: Is there a particular need for u to use global assignment operators? `<<-`?